# How to solve the classNotFoundException warnings when running Kafka Connect on windows?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have checked multiple topics on the StackOverflow and Kafka Jira board and found that these warnings can be suppressed from connect-log4j.properperties file by setting reflections to log at error level.
But how to solve these warnings completely.

```
C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\bin\windows>connect-distributed.bat C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\config\connect-distributed.properties
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\logs\connect.log (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
        at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.<clinit>(ConnectDistributed.java:57)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [connectAppender].
[2020-01-24 13:26:44,426] INFO WorkerInfo values:
        jvm.args = -Xmx256M, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35, -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -Dkafka.logs.dir=C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0/logs, -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0/config/connect-log4j.properties
        jvm.spec = , OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_222-2-ojdkbuild, 25.222-b10
        jvm.classpath = C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\activation-1.1.1.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\argparse4j-0.7.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\commons-cli-1.4.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\connect-api-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\connect-basic-auth-extension-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\connect-file-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\connect-json-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\connect-mirror-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\connect-mirror-client-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\connect-runtime-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\connec
t-transforms-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\guava-20.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\hk2-api-2.5.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jackson-core-2.10.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jackson-dataformat-csv-2.10.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jackson-module-s
cala_2.13-2.10.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jersey-client-2.28.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jersey-common-2.28.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jersey-container-servlet-2.28.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jersey-hk2-2.28.jar;C:\u
hx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jersey-media-jaxb-2.28.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jersey-server-2.28.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jetty-client-9.4.20.v20190813.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jetty-continuation-9.4.20.v20190813.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jetty-http-9.4.20.v20190813.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jetty-io-9.4.20.v20190813.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jetty-security-9.4.20.v20190813.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jetty-server-9.4.20.v20190813.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jetty-servlet-9.4.20.v20190813.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jetty-servlets-9.4.20.v20190813.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jetty-util-9.4.20.v20190813.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka-clients-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka-log4j
-appender-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka-streams-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka-streams-examples-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka-streams-scala_2.13-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka-streams-test-utils-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka-tools-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0-javadoc.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0-javadoc.jar.asc;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0-scaladoc.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0-scaladoc.jar.asc;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0-sources.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0-sources.jar.asc;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0-test-sources.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0-test-sources.jar.asc;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka
_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0-test.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0-test.jar.asc;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\kafka_2.13-2.4.0.jar.asc;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\lz4-java-1.6.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\maven-artifact-3.6.1.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\metrics-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\netty-buffer-4.1.42.Final.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\netty-codec-4.1.42.Final.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\netty-common-4.1.42.Final.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\netty-handler-4.1.42.Final.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\netty-resolver-4.1.42.Final.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\netty-transport-native-e
poll-4.1.42.Final.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.42.Final.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\paranamer-2.8.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\reflections-0.9.11.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.1.2.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\scala-java8-compat_2.13-0.9.0.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\scala-library-2.13.1.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\scala-logging_2.13-3.9.2.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\scala-reflect-2.13.1.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.28.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\snappy-java-1.1.7.3.ja
r;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\zookeeper-3.5.6.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\zookeeper-jute-3.5.6.jar;C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs\zstd-jni-1.4.3-1.jar
        os.spec = Windows Server 2012 R2, amd64, 6.3
        os.vcpus = 1
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerInfo:71)
[2020-01-24 13:26:44,468] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:90)
[2020-01-24 13:26:44,588] INFO Loading plugin from: C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\plugins\kafka-connect-redis-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:241)
[2020-01-24 13:26:50,288] INFO Reflections took 5556 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 1898 keys and 8262 values [using 1 cores] (org.reflections.Reflections:232)
[2020-01-24 13:26:50,386] WARN could not get type for name io.lettuce.core.dynamic.support.TypeInformation from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections:396)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name io.lettuce.core.dynamic.support.TypeInformation
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:428)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:327)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:263)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:255)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.lettuce.core.dynamic.support.TypeInformation
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
        ... 11 more
[2020-01-24 13:26:50,396] WARN could not get type for name org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections:396)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:428)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:327)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:263)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:255)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)

. . . . same logs . . . . .
---------------------------

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
        ... 11 more
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? n

C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\bin\windows>
```

Connector configurations distributed mode:

```
{
  "name": "RedisSinkConnector1",
  "config": {
    "name": "RedisSinkConnector1",
    "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector",

    "tasks.max": 3,
    "topics": "cache_record",
    "redis.hosts": "XXX.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX",
    "redis.password": "XXXXXXX",

    "schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "errors.tolerance" : "all",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name" :"fail_record",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable" : true,
    "errors.log.enable" : true,
    "errors.log.include.messages" : true,

  }
}
```

Kafka version: kafka_2.13-2.4.0
Connector: https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-redis
OS: Windows Server

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question to include some more detail: (1) Which version of Kafka? (2) which connector are you using (3) your connector configuration

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, I have updated the logs and other things as well will you suggest anything now. Thanks, for the quick response.

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, but if I were you I would simply try the Docker images - it's a ton easier to get working, and then once you've built what you want, then you could focus on getting it to run on Windows if it really needs to. Here's an example Docker Compose that you can use which shows installing a Kafka Connect connector too: https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/influxdb-and-kafka/docker-compose.yml

Comment: I am having my development environment as Linux and it is running smoothly, however, our other component are very much dependent and deployed on windows env

Answer (score 2):

There are several open pull requests in Kafka that fix quoting issues around forming the CLASSPATH in the Kafka start scripts. Mainly, I think the problem is paths with spaces breaks the script

That being said, you could try setting the CLASSPATH variable yourself to include the path of the folder containing the kafka libraries, or you can run Connect in a supported Linux environment such as a VM, WSL/Cygwin, or Docker

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't see any spaces in my current Kafka directory though, I have updated the CLASSPATH=C:\xxx\apache-kafka\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\libs env variable in kafka-run-class.bat, kafka-server-start.bat and windows environment as well. Still getting the same warnings. from the logs what I can see is Kafka is able to scan all libs files that come along with Kafka.

Comment: Your updated question has 2 errors. 1) your `plugin.path` for connect does not include the parent path of the Redis connector 2) looks like you're getting access denied by windows when trying to make a log file, which again would be resolvable by running Kafka in a Linux environment, where it's throughly tested